# How to Crop an Image's Height Without Changing Size and Ratio (React/CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm attempting to crop this image in CSS so that the image fills the entire container and stays the same ratio as the original file, without changing the image size any larger than what it needs to fit the container. Just like what photoshop does with the crop tool:

In this example, the images size doesnt change in either direction, and fills the container its in, but the image is cropped on its Y axis from the bottom to the top:

Heres a video example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6NGM.jpg

Here's a simple working code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-frog-vkvxp?file=/src/App.js:0-1402

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import img from "./img.jpg";

const appContainerStyle = {
  position: "relative",
  height: "100vh",
  width: "100vw",
  backgroundColor: "rgb(70,70,70)"
};

const btnContainerStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"
};

export default function App() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);
  const imageStyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    height: `${height}%`,
    width: "100%",
    background: `url(${img})`,
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundPosition: "top",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
  };
  return (
    <div style={appContainerStyle}>
      <div style={imageStyle}></div>
      <div style={btnContainerStyle}>
        <button
          style={{ height: "50px", width: "100px" }}
          onClick={() => {
            height > 0 && setHeight(height - 10);
          }}
        >
          Smaller
        </button>
        <button
          style={{ height: "50px", width: "100px" }}
          onClick={() => {
            height < 100 && setHeight(height + 10);
          }}
        >
          Bigger
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

//image is changing size when the height is changed, 
//I would like for it to stay the same size, but crop when the height is changed
```

My problem is that it crops the image sometimes fine, but it also sometimes changes the image size.

The image shouldn't scale in its container, it should only be cropped in the window.

Here's a flawed approach: [stillscales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV84B.jpg)

As you can see, the image is cropped until it reaches a point where the image is then being scaled in its container.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you change the height of the image with the button? How should it fill the whole screen when you actively change the height of the image?

Comment: @Gh05d My bad it should fill the entire container, not screen. Ill change that. It also should be the same proportion or ratio, and should only crop on the Y axis or the height.

Comment: @Gh05d The example shows how when you press the "smaller" btn, it scales the image to a certain point and then starts to crop the height, the image stays covering the container, but the image needs to not change its size any larger than what it needs to be to fit the container.

Answer (score 0):

create an image container with overflow of hidden so this way when you move image it won't show the outside of box.

then you have to set the image position to relative. this helps to move the image from its position without breaking the design.

after that you can give the image left, right, top and bottom positions to set the image position and the overflow will be hidden.

the html:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"/>
</div>
```

the css:

```
.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
```

this is how you crop the image if you need more help ask in the comment for react code

Comment: Maybe your on to something, but this looks like you just took the image and moved it down. I need to crop the image from the bottom to the top without changing its center axis and changing its size,  unless it is to cover a container that has been resized within the window. The ratio of the image must be preserved also.

Comment: this method doesnt change the size but if your usecase is to crop it and you want to like save it later and stuff... i recommend using a canvas library they can help you a lot. but if it's just for showing you can change the size of container in one case or you can use the method at top but css wont help you creating a croped image. css will just hide some parts of it

Comment: Thanks for your help, i found a solution before asking this question, I was just interested in a better approach. It seems my approach may not be improved upon, but im still open to new responses.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `backgroundSize: "cover"` to `backgroundSize: "150%"`.

```
const imageStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  height: `${height}%`,
  width: "100%",
  background: `url(${img})`,
  backgroundSize: "150%",
  backgroundPosition: "top",
  backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
};
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-buck-89pv4

Comment: Thank you @Manas, but this just makes the image more zoomed in and doesn't cover the window without oversizing it. When the window size is any bigger than 1000px wide the image is so large you can hardly see what it is. Heres an example of what i want: https://imgur.com/za9IIIW

Comment: If you make the window smaller the image also doesnt cover.

Comment: You can control them using media queries, because if you want the background as cover then as you will reduce the height it will take the new height as the container.

Comment: This is not the answer i am looking for, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user67 This is something I have come up with https://4q4fh.csb.app/

Comment: As i explained before, shrink the window down to around iphone size and the picture doesnt cover the entire container...

Comment: @user67 It is working perfectly fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sq6c.png

Comment: Now press the smaller button and watch it scale lol

Comment: @user67 Then the best way is to use `pseudo-elements` to make an overlay over the image.

Comment: Im sure you can do this without pseudo-elements, I know of a way already, but i was looking to stay away from it.